# How to remove from screen programmatically created textviews?

Tags: kotlin, textview, constraintset

In my routine (generateView()) I am creating a set of textViews (actually letter tiles) arranged in a constraint layout (reglette). To create the textviews I am using the expression 'val childView = TextView(requireActivity())' and then adjust the different parameters of the view. Elsewhere in the fragment I set onTouchListeners on those created views. And this works all fine.

Problem is when I call the routine for the second time and I want to get rid of the first set of views to replace them with a new one. I tried to use 'set.clear(view.id)' but the views remain on the screen and the new set overrides them.

I am doing something wrong ? Here the code of the routine:

```
private fun generateView(tirage:CharArray) {
    val set = ConstraintSet()
    val parentLayout = binding.reglette
    var i = 0

    set.clone(parentLayout)
    for (v in parentLayout.children)
        set.clear(v.id)
    set.applyTo(parentLayout)

    listLettre.clear()

    val dummyLeft = TextView(requireActivity())
    listLettre.add(dummyLeft)
    listPos.add(i)
    listIndex.add(i++)

    for (lettre in tirage) {
        val childView = TextView(requireActivity())
        childView.id = View.generateViewId()
        childView.width = LARGEUR_LETTRE.toInt()
        childView.height = LARGEUR_LETTRE.toInt()
        childView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lettre)
        childView.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        childView.text = lettre.toString()
        childView.textSize = 34f
        childView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD)
        parentLayout.addView(childView, i - 1)
        listLettre.add(childView)
        listPos.add(i)
        listIndex.add(i++)
    }

    val dummyRight = TextView(requireActivity())
    listLettre.add(dummyRight)
    listPos.add(i)
    listIndex.add(i)

    val premL = listLettre.drop(1).first()

    val pad = (parentLayout.width - (tirage.size * LARGEUR_LETTRE.toInt())) / 2

    set.clone(parentLayout)
    set.connect(
        premL.id,
        ConstraintSet.START,
        ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
        ConstraintSet.START,
        pad
    )

    val windowedList = listLettre.drop(1).dropLast(1).windowed(2, 1, false)

    for (pair in windowedList)
        set.connect(
            pair.last().id,
            ConstraintSet.START,
            pair.first().id,
            ConstraintSet.END
        )

    set.applyTo(parentLayout)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually `set.clear(view)` is removing all constraints from the view, not the view itself. The command to remove a view is

```
parentLayout.removeView(view)
```

or, to remove them all

```
parentLayout.removeAllViews()
```